# How to run a background process in response to selection change event in VSTO Office add-in?

Tags: c#, vsto, async-await

I have an VSTO application-level add-in, with my own custom task pane. I'm trying to intercept the SelectionChange event, and display information in my custom task pane that's relevant to the selection. I do know how to do that synchronously.

However the process of fetching the information to display is slow, and I don't want to block the application while I fetch the information. Furthermore, the user may change the selection several times, and I want to cancel any in-progress "fetch" operation if this happens.

I've tried await-ing the long-running operation, but since I don't have a form open, there is [no synchronization context in place](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/synchronizationcontext-odds-and-ends.html), hence I get an InvalidOperationException  (cross-thread operation not valid) as soon as I try to update the controls on my task pane.

```
async void Application_WindowSelectionChange(PowerPoint.Selection selection)
{
    var results = await MyLongRunningOperation(cancellationTokenSource.Token);

    myControl.Text = DescribeResults(results); // BOOM!
}
```

What's the best way to overcome this? I tried doing as Stephen suggested in the link above, by putting the following at the start of the selection-changed event handler:

```
SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext())
```

That didn't work. Suddenly all my other event handlers started erroring, saying "BeginInvoke cannot be called until the handle has been created". I tried putting the same code at the start of *every* event handler, in case it was an all-or-nothing deal. That didn't work either. Perhaps I should have created *one* `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` object and used it for all the handlers - but I'm aware I'm now clutching at straws.

If that doesn't work, what other approaches should I try? Is `BeginInvoke` still the way to go, or can I jump over to the UI thread some other way?

Comment: Try setting the sync context earlier on, during init code. Alternatively, wrap the setting of the context only if the sync context Current is null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Suddenly all my other event handlers started erroring, saying "BeginInvoke cannot be called until the handle has been created".

That's curious. I'm also grasping at straws, but try this:

```
Control control = new Control();
IntPtr handle = control.Handle;
```

instead of calling `SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext` directly. You *may* need to do this at the beginning of each event.

(Idea taken from [this blog entry](http://www.ikriv.com/dev/dotnet/MysteriousHang.html)).

Comment: This works, thanks. It seems that I can get away with doing this immediately before the first `await`. And I only needed to do it in the event handler that doesn't already create a form.